# c++: using type safety to distinguish types oftwo int arguments

Tags: c++, type-safety

I have various functions with two int arguments (I write both the functions and the calling code myself). I am afraid to confuse the order of argument in some calls.

How can I use type safety to have compiler warn me or error me if I call a function with wrong  sequence of arguments (all arguments are int) ?

I tried typedefs: Typedef do not trigger any compiler warnings or errors:

```
typedef int X; typedef int Y; 

void foo(X,Y); 

X x; Y y; 

foo(y,x); // compiled without warning)
```

Comment: You might find something like this useful: http://calumgrant.net/units/units.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will have to create wrapper classes.  Lets say you have two different units (say, seconds and minutes), both of which are represented as ints.  You would need something like the following to be completely typesafe:

```
class Minute
{
public:
    explicit Minute(int m) : myMinute(m) {}
    operator int () const { return myMinute; }

private:
    int myMinute;
};
```

and a similar class for seconds.  The explicit constructor prevents you accidentally using an `int` as a `Minute`, but the conversion operator allows you to use a `Minute` anywhere you need an `int`.

Comment: For a more complete and generic implementation you might also check out http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/boost/strong_typedef.hpp

Answer (score 4):

`typedef` creates type aliases. As you've discovered, there's no type safety there.

One possibility, depending on what you're trying to achieve, is to use `enum`. That's not fully typesafe either, but it's closer. For example, you can't pass an int to an enum parameter without casting it.

Answer (score -6):

Get a post-it note. Write on it, in big letters, "X FIRST! THEN Y!" Stick it to your computer screen. I honestly don't know what else to advise. Using wrapper classes is surely overkill, when the problem can be solved with a post-it and a magic marker.

Comment: Ask developers of geographic software. Is it lat/long or long/lat? A classic case where wrapper classes do work, and post its don't.